# Recyclerview on item click set image to another imageview in activity

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-glide

I'm working on Recyclerview, and I want to set an image to center imageview from Recyclerview's selected item

[image]

> Error : You must pass in a non null View

here I'm trying to set an image to imageview located in `activity_set_back.xml` from `Onclick` method of Recyclerview's

I have: `moviesList(ArrayList)` that hold all URL
and I'm getting position on click
only thing I need to do is set that image to img_back(Imageview) Shown in this code

MoviesAdapter.class

> this is my adapter

```
    public class MoviesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MoviesAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    String string_url;
    String clicked_url;
    private ArrayList<Image> moviesList;

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        public ImageView img_backimage;
        public ImageView img_back;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            img_backimage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_backimage);
            img_back =(ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_edit_this);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);


        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int position = getLayoutPosition(); // gets item position
            clicked_url= moviesList.get(position).getPath();
            Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),position+"",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Glide.with(view.getContext()).load(clicked_url)
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                    .fitCenter()
                    .crossFade()
                    .into(img_back);
        }

    }

    public MoviesAdapter(ArrayList<Image> moviesList) {
        this.moviesList = moviesList;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_list_row, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(rootView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        string_url= moviesList.get(position).getPath();
        Glide.with(holder.img_backimage.getContext()).load(string_url)
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .fitCenter()
                .crossFade()
                .into(holder.img_backimage);
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return moviesList.size();
    }
}
```

> image_list_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


 <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_single_item"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingLeft="4dp"
        android:paddingRight="4dp"
        android:paddingTop="6dp">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_backimage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/background"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

> activity_set_back.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.weblogicindia.paint.SetBackActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_Paint_Area_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/grid_view_container">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rl_Paint_Area2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_edit_this"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/background"/>


        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/grid_view_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: `img_back` is null, which means `itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_edit_this)` is returning null, which is happening because there is no `View` in the `image_list_row` layout with ID `img_edit_this`. That `ImageView` is in `activity_set_back`. That `ImageView` should not be a member of your `ViewHolder` class, since it's not a list item `View`. Remove it from the `ViewHolder`, and use an interface to pass the click to the `Activity`, and have the `Activity` do the Glide call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here your `imageview`- `img_edit_this` is inside your activity and not inside the itemview. Inorder to access the imageview in your activity from adapter, you first need to pass a listner from your activity to adapter during adapter initilalisation. Then use this listener in your adapter to change the imageview in activity.

First create an interface like this

```
public interface RecyclerImageClick {
void onCenterImageChange(String imagePath);
}
```

Make your activity implement this, for egs

```
public class MembersList extends AppCompatActivity implements RecyclerImageClick
```

Now implement the method `onCenterImageChange(String imagePath)` in activity

Now when initialising adapter, pass this listner into it along with arraylist like this

```
data= new MoviesAdapter(ArrayList<Image> moviesList,this);
```

Now change your adapter constructor like this

```
private RecyclerImageClick listener;
public MoviesAdapter(ArrayList<Image> moviesList,RecyclerImageClick listener) {
        this.moviesList = moviesList;
        this.listener=listener;
    }
```

Now inside the adapter's imageview click listener call `listener.onCenterImageChange(imagePath)`

Now inside your activity, declare your `imageview` and set it to the image path passed from `adapter`

Comment: i'm beginner in android, thank you for your valuable time

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `onclick` method of `RecyclerView` to detect child click instead use `ClickListener` on child view in `bind` method as in

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        string_url= moviesList.get(position).getPath();
        Glide.with(holder.img_backimage.getContext()).load(string_url)
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .fitCenter()
                .crossFade()
                .into(holder.img_backimage);
        holder.itemView.setonClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){          
            Glide.with(view.getContext()).load(string_url)
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                    .fitCenter()
                    .crossFade()
                    .into(img_back);
        });
    }
```