# How do i call a method of an Activity from its Recycler View Adapter? Or better,How to access the UI elements of an activity from the adapter?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have a Recycler View in ItemActivity and its Adapter as a seperate class ItemAdapter.Now based on the count of the Item chosen i need to update the text on a button placed in ItemActivity.How can it be done?

note:I have passed getApplicationContext() as the context to the Adapter.It passes the GlobalValue context which I have set in the manifest.

```
<application
    android:name=".GlobalValues"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

### The following is my ItemActivity.xaml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    tools:context=".ItemPickerActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/itemstext"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Choose Items"
        android:fontFamily="@font/exo_semibold"
        android:textColor="@color/dark_grey"              
        />    
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="3dp"
        android:id="@+id/pickerRecview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/itemstext"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/checkout"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:background="@color/go_green"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Total"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Rs XXX"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:fontFamily="@font/exo_semibold"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Checkout"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/exo_semibold"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TotalItems"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:text="xx Items"
            android:fontFamily="@font/exo_semibold"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp" />   
    </RelativeLayout>        
</RelativeLayout>
```

**And this is how i instantiate the adapter object**

```
ItemPickerAdapter adapter = new ItemPickerAdapter(getApplicationContext(), ItemsList);

            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I need to change the value of ItemCount in my ItemActitvity from the adapter!Please advise me on how it is possible.Thanks!

Comment: use an Interface with callback.

Comment: you can pass a listener from your activity to the adapter, check this example>> https://stackoverflow.com/a/49397985/8009433

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to make the Adapter class an inner class contained within the Activity class. Then make the View you need to manipulate a global variable.

Comment: Thank you!That is possible,but i also want to use that adapter for another Recycler View in a  different activity.

Comment: Interface is the way then.

Answer (score 0):

Change the adapter instantiation in your activity from:

```
ItemPickerAdapter adapter = new ItemPickerAdapter(getApplicationContext(), ItemsList);
```

to this:

```
ItemPickerAdapter adapter = new ItemPickerAdapter(this, ItemsList);
```

meaning you pass the activity's context and not the application's context.  
Then in your adapter class declare this:

```
MainActivity mainActivity = (MainActivity) context;
```

replace `MainActivity` with your activity's class name and `context` with the name of the  parameter of your adapter class constructor for the Context.  
 
Now you can access every public method, property, view in your activity by:

```
mainActivity.something
```

**Edit1**: Use a variable in your activity class

```
Context mainContext = this;
```

then instantiate the adapter:

```
ItemPickerAdapter adapter = new ItemPickerAdapter(mainContext, ItemsList);
```

**Edit2**: If you want to access your activity's UI elements like a `TextView` from your adapter, create a public method inside the activity class:

```
public void setTextViewText(String text) {
    myTextView.setText(text);
}
```

and call it from the adapter:

```
mainActivity.setTextViewText("some text");
```

Comment: I tried that,but it doesnt work...
--ItemPickerAdapter adapter = new ItemPickerAdapter(this, ItemsList);--
here 'this' is  considered as a Firebase valueEventListener...i don't know why

Comment: Where is this code? Isn't it inside your activity class?

Comment: Inside a method in my activity

Comment: the problem actually is not with accessing the method! It's about accessing the Ui elements from another class

Comment: You mean like TextViews etc?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following

Create one interface

```
public interface ItemCountListner {
  void onItemCountUpdate(int count);
}
```

Implement interface in your activity and pass the reference to your adapter

```
class MainActivity implements ItemCountListner {

---------
ItemPickerAdapter adapter = new ItemPickerAdapter(MainActivity.this, ItemsList, this);
---------

//implemented method
void onItemCountUpdate(int count){
 // update your ui
}
}
```

Add argument in your adapter constructor

> public ItemPickerAdapter(Context context, List itemList,
>   ItemCountListner listener)

Update your ui by calling

```
listener.onItemCountUpdate(count);
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your RecyclerView Adapter, you can define your own viewModel and inside that, you can attach onClick on any component you want. For eg:

```
 public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        private TextView eachFeaturesName;


        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            eachFeaturesName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.eachFeaturesName);
            }
    }
```

And inside onBindViewHolder function , you can do this:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyViewHolder myViewHolder, final int position) {

//myViewHolder.eachFeaturesName.setonViewClickListener(...)

}
```

This is an easy way to use onClickListener on RecyclerView